# Rails convention - placing logic in view vs controller vs partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

## Messages are displayed green if sent by the current user, and blue otherwise. Following Rails convention, where does that logic belong?

---

### Introdution

The user will visit `/group/:id` to see the list of messages, so the corresponding view is **views/groups/show.html.erb** and the corresponding controller is **controllers/groups_controller.rb**.

The message we want to display are in an array in **@group**, as **@group.messages**. The array is sorted by timestamp.

The code to style the color of the message is not important, but for simplicity purposes we will say there are two class selectors (one for **from** and one for **to**) and we can simply add a class attribute to the div that a message is within to change its color.

Both the user's sent and received messages are held in the array **@group.messages**.
If we have an individual message stored in **message**, we can test if it was sent by the current user with:

```
if session[:user_id] == message.user_id
```

---

### Problem

Messages are ordered by timestamp and will need to be displayed in that order. For this reason, I can't see any clean way of handling the logic in the controller.

I would like to keep as much logic as possible out of the views and especially out of the partials, but after considering the options for rendering **sent** and **received** messages in different ways, the cleanest option I've found is to put the logic in the **message** partial.

---

#### Handling the logic in the message partial:

```
<% if message.user.id == session[:user_id] %>
  <div class="to">
    <p> <%= message.body %> </p>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="from">
    <p> <%= message.body %> </p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Pros:**

- This method handles the logic with one if statement that is clean and simple
- It allows us to make the code DRY because we won't have to use the logic anywhere else if we want it on other pages
- Since every message only has a body, we don't have to make another partial to display messages without this formatting

**Cons:**

- The logic is in the partial! I think people I'm working with or other programmers or even myself would first look in the controller *then* in the view *then* in the partial to make any changes or see the code
- This doesn't *feel* like normal Rails convention

---

#### Handling the logic in the view:

**Possibly two clean solutions -**
1) Style the messages inside the logic ***or***
2) Render a different partial for sent/received messages

**Styling inside the logic:**

```
<% @group.messages.each do |message| %>
  <% if message.user.id == session[:user_id] %>
    <div class="to">
      <p> message.body </p>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="from">
      <p> message.body </p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Rendering different partials:**

```
<% @group.messages.each do |message| %>
  <% if message.user.id == session[:user_id] %>
    <%= render :partial => '/messages/sent_message', :message => message %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render :partial => '/messages/received_message', :message => message %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Pros:**

- Either view solution keeps the logic out of the partial
- It makes sense that showing something as one color or another is decided in the view
- The view solution using two partials is clean and allows us to avoid styling within logic which also means that we can change the style within the partials and affect the look of messages everywhere.

**Cons:**

- Both view options mean that our code is no longer DRY. Using these methods will mean that if we want the same functionality on 3 other pages, we will have to write the same code 3 more times
- It makes sense that a view shouldn't be deciding anything
- The view solution using two partials means that we will crowd the views/messages folder with partials, and still not have a default partial for rendering messages
- Both of the view solutions just feel dirty in my opinion

---

### My main points about my solutions -

- No option allows for the logic to be held within the controller
- Placing the logic inside the view means that to provide the same functionality on multiple pages, the same code will be written in more than one place
- The option that looks the cleanest and makes the most sense to me means putting logic inside a partial, and there *must* be a better way.. right?
- None of the solutions seem like they follow Rails convention

---

#### Which of the three options I coded *best* follow Rails convention?

#### Is it possible to place the logic in the controller?

#### Is there a better way to design this so that there is a clear solution following Rails convention?

Answer (score 3):

What you probably have realized is that each of the three versions you described is either not DRY or not scalable. You've done a great job analyzing pros and cons of each option, so there is very little for me to add there. :)

To add *presentation functionality* to your models, Rails community uses Presenters. There is a great article on Presenters [here](http://hawkins.io/2011/06/present_yourself/) that explains more about them.

Basically, you'll want to have one partial for message:

```
<div class=<%=@presenter.css_class%>>
  <p> <%= message.body %> </p>
</div>
```

Then Presenter:

```
class MessagesPresenter
  def initialize(message, current_user)
    @message = message
    @current_user = current_user
  end

  def css_class
    message.user == current_user ? 'to' : 'from'
  end

  private

  attr_reader :message, :current_user
end
```

And controller:

```
@presenter = MessagesPresenter.new(@message, current_user)
```

Voila! The presenter is available in both views and partials and is a great place to stash all presentation logic.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only difference in these examples in the CSS class, you're repeating yourself quite a bit. Can't you add or remove a class on the tag depending on whether the tag belongs to the `current_user` or not?

This is really a presentation issue, and you can handle this simple logic for displaying the correct CSS tag using decorators (http://johnotander.com/rails/2014/03/07/decorators-on-rails/). I recommend using Draper (https://github.com/drapergem/draper).

First, for simplicity, add a `current_user` helper method to `application_controller.rb` to return the authenticated user.

Add a Decorator:

#### MessageDecorator.rb

```
def recipient_class
  user_id == current_user.id ? "to" : "from"  # (user_id delegates to message object)
end
```

Now your views can have much cleaner logic

#### Views

**Message Partial:**

```
<div class="<%= message.recipient_class %>">
  <p><%= message.body %></p>
</div>
```

**collection partial in  the main view:**

```
<%= render partial: "message", collection: @messages, as: :message %>
```

Finally, call `decorate` on messages in your controller action:

```
@messages = @group.messages.decorate
```

**EDIT**

You can also use a simple helper method rather than a decorator:

```
def css_class_for_message(message)
  message.user_id == current_user.id ? "to" : "from"
end
```

Comment: Does `current_user` in `application_controller.rb` need to be a helper method? I thought that made it available for views, and this situation only needs it to be available in the controller, right?

Comment: Yes, in order for it to be accessible from the decorator it does need to be a helper method. You'll also need to declare `include Draper::LazyHelpers` if using Draper.

Comment: Could you justify adding a decorator instead of just adding a method to the model just like `recipient_class`? Of course you would have to make the current user's id available to that method, or pass it to the method. Using a decorator in this situation seems like a bit overkill to me. I've never used one before though, so I'm curious to know what you think about that.

Comment: The model isn't concerned with the view, and like you say, `current_user` isn't accessible. You're right that it may be overkill for one use case, however, I'd prefer to use a helper method like `class_for_message(message)` than modify the model.

Comment: I think that the edit you provided will most likely be the answer for the one case I have. Of course, in the real world you usually aren't concerned about one case and you have to prepare ahead. So I'll work with both Decorators and Presenters to see which more naturally fits in with my design before deciding which will be the correct choice for the future. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may want to check this article for a nice side by side comparison: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/decorators-compared-to-strategies-composites-and @MatthewCliatt